# Spring-Boot security - Resource folder doesn't work

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a quick issue which am not really sure how to sort this out yet.

The issue is that, I'm using Thymeleaf, and was working perfectly fine until I've introduced the Springboot security. Since then, the styling isn't working at all. Looks like the static folder isn't seen for some reason. I've tried several structures to make it work but still no luck. I've tried to include in resource folder static folder, then resource folder (again) with no luck. I've also tried to rename the static into public, still no luck. I've noticed that if you include the URL somewhere on the web it works but if you include the URL somewhere on your local machine doesn't work. So I'm 100% sure there is a problem with the structure of the folders or the Spring configuration.

Any help, would be really much appreciated.

Spring security configuration class:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/default")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/static/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/createUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

}

WebConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig {

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385205/confusion-around-spring-security-anonymous-access-using-java-config for your issue with things in the `static` folder. Please post the controller code for the page that shows user info. It's up to your code to not return objects for which the user is not permitted to see.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for your help. There isn't any controller for the user details, you mean the home page? Regarding the thymeleaf, I've added permit all to the resource folder where it contains all the css and javascript files. It's the same as the pointed thread in my opinion. Thank you

Comment: You should create separate SO question for each of your issues. Not include various issues/questions into one.

Comment: I've separated them. Thank you for the heads-up. :)